# Are open/read/write buffered or not?

Tags: c, linux

Only open/read/write functions are used in my program, but oprofile shows me that:

```
20537     2.9883  tyn_indexer              tyn_indexer              nodes_term32_flush
11966     1.7411  vmlinux                  vmlinux                  jbd2_journal_commit_transaction
11733     1.7072  vmlinux                  vmlinux                  __strnlen_user
10741     1.5629  vmlinux                  vmlinux                  nobh_truncate_page
9728      1.4155  vmlinux                  vmlinux                  generic_file_buffered_write
9443      1.3740  vmlinux                  vmlinux                  mpage_da_map_and_submit
9023      1.3129  vmlinux                  vmlinux                  do_get_write_access
7283      1.0597  vmlinux                  vmlinux                  invalidate_interrupt31
5894      0.8576  vmlinux                  vmlinux                  write_cache_pages_da
5332      0.7758  vmlinux                  vmlinux                  journal_submit_commit_record
5316      0.7735  vmlinux                  vmlinux                  hugetlbfs_symlink
```

How generic_file_buffered_write comes out, and are open/read/write functions buffered?

Comment: Buffering occurs at many different levels.  Which level are you asking about?

Comment: {stdin,stdout,stderr} are always buffered. If your program  fprintf()s to stdout or stderr, the output will be buffered.

Comment: I'd expect `open` to be an unbuffered system call, but `generic_file_buffered_write` might be pulled in by something else. What was the oprofile command used? Is your program statically linked, or dynamically linked? If you do an `nm` on your program, do you see the name `generic_file_buffered_write`?

Comment: @William Pursell I don't know too much about how many cache levels there are, so I just mean comparing to "fopen/fwrite/fread"

Comment: @gbulmer it's dynamically linked, and I don't see generic_file_buffered_write if using nm -DC

Comment: It's a kernel function, the other functions to do with interrupts and journal commits should have tipped you off. Here: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.2.11/mm/filemap.c#L2458

Comment: @wildplasser: stderr is not fully buffered (either line buffered or unbuffered), but that's almost immaterial.  None of the standard I/O streams is manipulated by the programmer directly calling open, close, read, write (though the underlying implementation of streams certainly uses them).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: IMHO stderr *is* buffered. It just chooses to flush the buffer more often.

Comment: @wildplasser: That's up to the implementation. Per the standard `stderr` shall not be fully buffered by default. It can be line buffered or unbuffered, and almost all implementations choose to make it unbuffered.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you mean by buffering. When C programmers say these functions are unbuffered, what it means is that there is no buffer *local to the application process* that could prevent other processes from seeing data in a consistent fashion. The implementation of these functions (in the kernel) is free to do as much or as little buffering as it likes as long as it's done in a way that's transparent to application processes (i.e. does not interfere with whether or when they see data on the file).

On the other hand, stdio is (usually) buffered, meaning that if you use stdio (the `FILE *` functions from `stdio.h`) to access a file, data may be read from the underlying file descriptor and buffered in your process's memory space where other processes cannot see it *before you actually intend to read and use it*, or data you have written might remain buffered in your process's memory space where other processes cannot see it long after you wrote it (unless you call `fflush`).

Answer (score 0):

The `read` and `write` system calls have quite arbitrary semantics, which depend entirely on the device that you are interacting with.

The `read` function can do diverse things. For instance, if you're reading from a TTY driver in cooked mode ("canonical input processing"), and ask for 1 byte, `read` will not return that one byte until a complete line is actually available. But even in a raw mode, of course there are still buffers. Data is received in an interrupt-driven fashion from the keyboard or serial port even while your process is not calling `read`, and sits in a buffer.

The `read` function can discard data. If you're reading sectors from a traditional Unix raw tape device, or datagrams from a datagram socket, and the buffer you're supplying is too small to hold an entire sector or packet, the excess data is truncated.

`write` to a file can return long before the data actually goes out to disk.